# How to cast a SQL bigint to C# equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, casting

I'm trying to cast a bigint from SQL Server into its equivalent in c#, but Visual Studio keeps forcing me to try to cast it to int, which throws a 'specified cast not valid' error. I've tried to cast it to long, Int64, int, etc. What would be the proper way of doing that? My code looks like this:

```
var id = 0;

//Omitted code

if (reader.Read())
{
    id = (int) reader["id"];
}

//More code
```

Comment: `id = Convert.ToInt64(reader["id"]);` maybe?

Comment: try `reader["id"].GetType()` to see what the actual type you need to cast to.

Comment: SQL Server's `bigint` is a 64-bit integer, which is equivalent to C#'s `long`. Can we see your SQL query and table/database definition? You are probably getting a wrong field.

Comment: BTW, what happens when you try to cast to `long`? Do you get run-time or compile-time error?

Comment: When I try to cast it to long, resharper yelled at me to cast to int. Explicitly setting the id type to Int64 worked.

Comment: OK, so this was a compile-time error, and it now works (both compile-time and run-time)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [`following table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) illustrates, SQL Server's `bigint` maps to .NET's `Int64` structure:

```
long id = 0;

//Omitted code

if (reader.Read())
{
    id = (long) reader["id"];
}
```

If this is throwing an `InvalidCastException` that you totally don't have a `bigint` in your dtaabase and you probably wanna be checking the actual type in the debugger using `reader["id"].GetType()`.

By the way notice how I replace your `var id = 0;` with `long id = 0;` which is actually declaring a variable of type `Int64` instead of `Int32`. If you wanna use C# variable inference make sure you are doing it the proper way: `var id = 0L;`

By the way if you don't wanna be casting you may try this alternative:

```
long id = 0;

//Omitted code

if (reader.Read())
{
    id = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int64`.

Source: ["System.Data.SqlTypes Namespace"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is your initial declaration with `var`. This is an implicitly typed variable and assigned at the first use. And it is assumed to be an int since you assign it 0.

Replace the declaration with `Int64 or long id = 0` and you should be fine

Comment: You could also do var id = 0L;

Comment: True, but I prefer to restrict var to really anonymous types, like projections in Linq. Not if you know the intended datatype. It's kind of lazy coding and can get you into trouble :)

Comment: In this case using `var` has nothing to do with anonymous types.

Comment: You *can* use `var` with anonymous types (`var x = new { .... }`), but here `id` is an `int` from the moment it's declared. There's nothing anonymous about it.

Comment: yes, you are right, I corrected to implicitly. Still I would not use var in these cases...

Comment: @Pleun: I wouldn't either--very hard to tell what type `id` is.